# Playing Audio in iOS: Delay in playing at certain times

Tags: ios, audio, delay, avaudioplayer, swift2

Long time lurker but first time poster, so please bear with me!

As a bit of background info the app is a multi-tasking puzzle, including some mental maths. When the user taps the correct answer, a sound should be played indicating they have answered correctly.

The issue I am experiencing is that the first time the sound is played there is a short delay where it appears to be fading in at the start. I have attempted to use AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID and AVAudioPlayer but am experiencing the same issue with both solutions.

I've [uploaded a short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9geCTG6j5uo) which illustrates my issue (note the difference between the first and subsequent pings).

Interestingly this delay doesn't occur for any sounds played soon after, however if no sound is played for ~10 seconds, then the same issue occurs when one is.

I can only assume this is a lower level issue to do with how iOS initialises and retains its audio hardware. I have attempted to play a silent piece of audio as per a few other suggestions, but to no avail.

A very simplified summary of my implementation is as follows:

```
import AudioToolbox

class myViewController: UIViewController {

    var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ping", ofType: "mp3")!), &soundID)
    }

    @IBAction func correctButtonPressed() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have only dealt with voice synthesis, so maybe it doesn't apply here, but: do you configure an `AVAudioSession` object somewhere? AFAIK it is used to express the intent of your audio, and its setup might mitigate the problem

Comment: I've not seen anything that uses `AVAudioSession` for this type of implementation. The code I've posted above is the only code that has anything to do with audio in my project. I'll have a quick look.

Comment: My best bet would be to 1. Get your app's audio session, 2, configure it, 3. explicitly set audio session active when the game starts

Comment: I've given that a go with the following code but it hasn't resolved the issue. `do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't Set AVAudioSession")
        }`

Comment: Reading about the function you use the docs state: "The interface does not provide level, positioning, looping, or **timing** control, and does not support simultaneous playback". You should probably look for another API more suitable for gaming.

Comment: Matt, do you find that there is a measurable delay that matches your perceptions? You can quantify the playback delay by wrapping your code with some timing constants like so: `let start = NSDate(); AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySoundID); let end = NSDate(); let timeInterval: Double = end.timeIntervalSinceDate(start); NSLog("interval \(interval)");`. This may help to determine if it's a code issue or something else. I've observed some strange behaviors with audio services since moving to iOS 9 in apps of mine.